# How to make soft keyboard static?

Tags: android

I'm trying to force the soft keyboard not to close down after I press enter in the EditText in my activity. What do I need to do so that the EditText will always be on focus and the soft keyboard will stay put even after pressing enter?

I used already in the manifest  `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"`

I also tried to use methods such as:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

---

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_view)),InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

---

```
EditText.requestFocus();
```

but it didn't change anything...
also, how can I make the EditText focused right when the activity opens up?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call this inside onCreate method of your activity. It will show the keyboard right when the activity shows up. And if you keep clicking enter , it will keep creating new line on your edit text and not close the keyboard, however the backbutton on the actual device will still close it

In Kotlin :-

```
window.setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE
        )
```

and if in case you have limited the edittext to one line only ... add the following code in the onCreate method below the above code

kotlin :-

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, event ->
            (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) || ((event.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) && (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN))
        }
```

Comment: While using it in the onCreate method indeed makes the keyboard pop up at the start, after I press enter it still closes. Also, it can't create a new line because I set the max lines in my EditText to 1

Comment: I updated the answer .. please check ... now the only way to close the keyboard is backbutton on device

Comment: Thanks, almost got it to work! The only problem I'm having now is that after I press enter the edit text isn't being focused anymore, how can I fix that? I tried requestFocus(), setSelected(true) and performClick() but they didn't work... Maybe it's the placement? I put those before I returned true in the OnEditorAction() method..

Comment: add editText.requestFocus() in the onCreate() method above the setSoftInputMode statement

Comment: More importantly... add this line in xml under that edit text ...             android:imeOptions="actionDone"

Answer (score 0):

There is a method of `EditText`, named `requestFocus()` to get focus on the `EditText`

For Example, inside `onCreate()` of activity

```
EditText date_birthday = findViewById(R.id.date_birthday);
date_birthday.requestFocus();
```

Comment: forgot to mention this method didn't work for me too